# Swift Error MQMD.Format Field is not valid

Tags: ibm-mq

Have a Apache Camel based app submitting a message to SWIFT over Websphere MQ

```
<SwMsg:TransferAnswer>Failed Storage</SwMsg:TransferAnswer>
   <SwMsg:TransferError>
      <SwMsg:ErrorCode>Sw.Gbl.MQMDError</SwMsg:ErrorCode>
      <SwMsg:ErrorText>MQMD.Format field is not valid</SwMsg:ErrorText>
   </SwMsg:TransferError>
```

tried settting JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format to MQSTR, MQFMT_NONE, MQRFH2 etc
tried changing the JMSMessage Type to Text, Bytes

still the blanket reject message is the only response

Comment: When you inspect the message produced by your app, what value is there?

Comment: looks like Swift expects a blank value as format type which in MQMD terms equals none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the header **JMS_IBM_Forma**t to blank solved the issue
However setting JMS_IBM_MQMD_Format to blank didnt help

this is the camel property i am setting and it working as expected